# How to set input default value with state and also manually update input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Very new to React, I have an input that I would like to set with state `quantity` when clicking a button the quantity updates but I also want to be able to manually update the input also which would also update the state value but unsure how to achieve this?

**JS**

```
const Input = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            quantity: 0
        }
    },

    updateQuantity() {
          this.setState({
            quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
        });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <input type="text" value={this.state.quantity}/>
              <button onClick={this.updateQuantity}>Update</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mwvjLqkg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onChange` event to your input, in order to change `quantity` manually

```js
const Input = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      quantity: 0
    }
  },

  updateQuantity() {
    this.setState({
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
    });
  },

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ quantity: +e.target.value })
  },

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.quantity} 
        onChange={ this.handleChange }
      />
      
      <button onClick={this.updateQuantity}>Update</button>
    </div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Input />, document.body.querySelector('.js-app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-app"></div>
```